# Issue with PHP code in XML structure

Tags: php, xml, for-loop

I have a php code with XML structure

```
$bookreq =<<<XML
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<soap:Header>
<AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns='http://epowerv5.amadeus.com.tr/WS'>
<WSUserName>****</WSUserName>
<WSPassword>****</WSPassword>
</AuthenticationSoapHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<BookFlight xmlns='http://epowerv5.amadeus.com.tr/WS'>
<OTA_AirBookRQ RecommendationID='0' CombinationID='0'>
<POS />
<TravelerInfo>

--------HERE CODE--------

</TravelerInfo>
<Fulfillment>
<DeliveryAddress>
<AddressLine>Amadeus Rezervasyon Dağıtım Sistemleri A.Ş.</AddressLine>
<AddressLine>Muallim Naci Caddesi No.41 Kat 4 Ortaköy</AddressLine>
<CityName>Istanbul</CityName>
<CountryName Code='TR' />
<PostalCode>34345</PostalCode>
</DeliveryAddress>
<PaymentDetails>
<PaymentDetail PaymentType='None'>
<BillingAddress>
<AddressLine>Amadeus Rezervasyon Dağıtım Sistemleri A.Ş.</AddressLine>
<AddressLine>Muallim Naci Caddesi No.41 Kat 4 Ortaköy</AddressLine>
<CityName>Istanbul</CityName>
<CountryName Code='TR' />
<PostalCode>34345</PostalCode>
</BillingAddress>
</PaymentDetail>
</PaymentDetails>
<PaymentText Name='TripName' Text='Payment text' />
<PaymentText Name='Notes' Text='Payment notes' />
</Fulfillment>
<Ticketing TicketType='BookingOnly'/>
</OTA_AirBookRQ>
</BookFlight>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML";
```

I need paste code

```
for($a=1;$a<=$adtpass;++$a)
{
  $adtblock;
}
```

Here 
--------HERE CODE--------

When I paste this code in xml structure, I have error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR).

How can I add this piece of code to the XML code that will be correct?

After Donald123 comment, rewrite my code

```
$bookreq = <<<XML
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<soap:Header>
<AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns='http://epowerv5.amadeus.com.tr/WS'>
<WSUserName>****</WSUserName>
<WSPassword>****</WSPassword>
</AuthenticationSoapHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<BookFlight xmlns='http://epowerv5.amadeus.com.tr/WS'>
<OTA_AirBookRQ RecommendationID='0' CombinationID='0'>
<POS />
<TravelerInfo>
XML;
for($a=1;$a<=$adtpass;++$a)
{
    echo $adtblock;
}
<<<XML
</TravelerInfo>
<Fulfillment>
<DeliveryAddress>
<AddressLine>Amadeus Rezervasyon Dağıtım Sistemleri A.Ş.</AddressLine>
<AddressLine>Muallim Naci Caddesi No.41 Kat 4 Ortaköy</AddressLine>
<CityName>Istanbul</CityName>
<CountryName Code='TR' />
<PostalCode>34345</PostalCode>
</DeliveryAddress>
<PaymentDetails>
<PaymentDetail PaymentType='None'>
<BillingAddress>
<AddressLine>Amadeus Rezervasyon Dağıtım Sistemleri A.Ş.</AddressLine>
<AddressLine>Muallim Naci Caddesi No.41 Kat 4 Ortaköy</AddressLine>
<CityName>Istanbul</CityName>
<CountryName Code='TR' />
<PostalCode>34345</PostalCode>
</BillingAddress>
</PaymentDetail>
</PaymentDetails>
<PaymentText Name='TripName' Text='Payment text' />
<PaymentText Name='Notes' Text='Payment notes' />
</Fulfillment>
<Ticketing TicketType='BookingOnly'/>
</OTA_AirBookRQ>
</BookFlight>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
XML;
```

This is what i have done, whether such code work, when I put variable `$bookreq`  in my cURL request?

Comment: read about heredoc http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: I don't understand, what you want. If you have a php file and want to insert some php-code, then open an editor and do it. By the way there is an error in your second code. After the code you inserted you need to write: "$bookreq1 .= <<<XML" - to append it to the existing variable. That php script will by itself not ouput anything. If you want to output the xml, you need to echo $bookreq1 at the end of the script.

Comment: I not need echo my code, I need when I paste for-loop in this xml structure, then can use $bookreq in curl request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make another PHP file to generate the full XML source, like in http://pastebin.com/nU9ZRuCD

Then in the main PHP file, you do include:

```
<?php

ob_start();
require 'my-xml-generator.php';
$bookreq = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


echo $bookreq;
```

Or use a template engine, example Twig: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/intro.html

Comment: and then I can use $bookreq in my cURL request?

Comment: Yes, all the content of the generated include (require) will be in the $bookreq.

Comment: Thaks for help,Rogeriolino